# How to utilize matplotlib to plot Grotrian Diagrams

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics, diagramming

I am currently looking for some tools to plot Grotrian diagrams for a particular element given the energy level details.
I have procured the atomic data regarding the energy level changes but am unable to utilize it to plot the respective Grotrian diagrams.

Is there any way using matplotlib to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking to have it automatically plot the diagram for you from the data? If so, could you share an example of the data that you have.

Comment: Do you have a formal definition of Grotrian diagrams? They look manageable by matplotlib, but maybe no-one else has *automated* plotting them from the atomic data. Opportunity!

Comment: @cphlewis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotrian_diagram Here is the description of Grotrian diagrams

Comment: @castle-bravo http://www.nhn.ou.edu/~jeffery/astro/atomic/grotrian/grotrian.html, You can find an example here

Comment: This is totally do-able in matplotlib, but I'm not going to do it for you. You will need to load the data into some numpy array data structures, which may involve using regexes or some of the tools in pandas to read from the text file - or you could put it in a csv manually. Then you need to iterate over those data structures and tell matplotlib to render the appropriate lines. `plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], 'k')` renders a straight line from (x0, y0) to (x1, y1) in black ('k'). There's a function for rendering arrows that's similar, but I don't remember the syntax off hand. Good luck.

Comment: @castle-bravo That's ample help :) Thanks a lot